# Queries about the "monotone" condition of Dirichlet's Test.

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Let $a>0$ be a constant.Consider the integral$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x\cos(ux)}{a^2+x^2}dx.$$

Can I use Dirichlet's Test to proof that it's uniformly convergent on $[\delta,+\infty) (\forall \delta>0)$?

Obviously,$$\lvert\int_0^{+\infty}\cos(ux)dx\rvert\le2,\forall u\ge\delta.$$

However, the function$\frac{x}{a^2+x^2}$ is not monotonically decreasing on $(0,+\infty)$ but on $(a,+\infty)$.It's different to the theorem's condition.

That also makes me think the deep meaning of the "monotone" condition in this theorem.

Comment: You can show that it's uniform on $[\delta, a + 1]$ and use Dirichlet's for $[a + 1, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this integration, there are two parameters in total.Hence, there are two different understandings.Moreover,taking $u=\frac{1}{n} $ and $x=n$,we have
$$
\left | \int_{0}^{n}\cos\left ( \frac{t}{n} \right )  dt\right |=n\sin(1)  >2
$$
So,I can't understand $\left | \int_{0}^{+\infty }\cos\left ( ut\right )  dt\right |\le 2$

**Case 1:**
If $a$ is fixed, we can consider the integration as
$$
I(u)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^{2}+x^{2}} d x
$$
Then we can always handle it in this way:
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^{2}+x^{2}} d x =\int_{0}^{a} \frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^{2}+x^{2}} d x+\int_{a}^{\infty } \frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^{2}+x^{2}} d x
$$
Note that
$$
\left | \int _0^{x}\cos(ut)dt \right | =\left | \frac{\sin(ux)}{u}  \right | \le \frac{1}{\delta } 
$$
Since the function$\frac{x}{a^2+x^2}$ is monotonically decreasing on $(a,+\infty)$,by Dirichlet's Test,$\int_{a}^{\infty } \frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^{2}+x^{2}} d x$ is uniformly convergent $\text { on }[\delta,+\infty)(\forall \delta>0)$.It follows that
$$
\forall \varepsilon >0,\exists A>0,\forall A_1,A_2>A,\forall u\in[\delta,+\infty):\left | \int _{A_1}^{A_2}\frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^{2}+x^{2}}dx \right |<\varepsilon  
$$
This proves that  $\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^{2}+x^{2}} d x$ is uniformly convergent $\text { on }[\delta,+\infty)$.

**Case 2:** If $u$ is fixed,then we can consider the integration as
$$
I(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^{2}+x^{2}} d x
$$
This situation requires the use of some techniques to avoid the question you mentioned.Clearly,for all fixed $\delta>0$,we have
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x \cos (u x)}{\delta^{2}+x^{2}} d x<\infty \quad\forall  \delta>0
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^2+x^{2}} d x&=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x \cos (u x)}{\delta ^2+x^{2}}\cdot \frac{\delta ^2+x^{2}}{a ^2+x^{2}}  d x\\
&=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x \cos (u x)}{\delta ^2+x^{2}}\cdot \left ( 1+\frac{a^2-\delta ^2}{a ^2+x^{2}}  \right )  d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $f(x)=1+\frac{a^2-\delta ^2}{a ^2+x^{2}}$.Since $f(x)$ is monotonic and $0<f(x)\le2$,by Abel's test,$\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{x \cos (u x)}{a^{2}+x^{2}} d x$ is uniformly convergent $\text { on }[\delta,+\infty)$.